# Feed not loading in full

Tags: bug, android-app

Feed page in app only loads one post.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: HM NOTE 1LTE

  - OS Version: 4.4.4 (V7.5.1.0.KHIMIDE)